# Avoid losing type info in return value

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, hlist

I'm trying to find a way to avoid losing type information in the return value for my method.

I have the following:

```
val defs0 = Default.mkDefault[Person, Some[String] :: Some[Int] :: HNil](Some("odd") :: Some(42) :: HNil)
```

Using IntelliJs "Add type annotation" gives the type:

```
Default.Aux[Person, ::[Some[String], ::[Some[Int], HNil]]]
```

This is fine, except I dont want to specify the fields of Person when I call mkDefault. So I created this:

```
object MkDefault {
  object toSome extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[P] = at[P](Some(_))
  }

  def apply[P, L <: HList, D <: HList]
  (p: P)
  (implicit
   lg: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L],
   mpr: Mapper.Aux[toSome.type, L, D]
  ): Default.Aux[P, D] =
    Default.mkDefault[P, D](mpr(lg.to(p)))
}
```

Now I can do:

```
val defs1 = MkDefault(Person("odd", 42))
```

Which is good, except the inferred type from IntellJ looks like this:

```
Default.Aux[Person, HNil]
```

**How can I make the inferred type of defs1 equal to the inferred type of defs0?**

**without having to specify the fields of class Person*

Comment: Use `mpr.Out` as an output type instead of `D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mpr.Out` instead of `D` as an output type:

```
object MkDefault {
  object toSome extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[P] = at[P](Some(_))
  }

  def apply[P, L <: HList, D <: HList]
  (p: P)
  (implicit
   lg: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L],
   mpr: Mapper.Aux[toSome.type, L, D]
  ): Default.Aux[P, mpr.Out] =
    Default.mkDefault[P, D](mpr(lg.to(p)))
}
```

Example:

```
scala> val defs1 = MkDefault(Person("odd", 42))
defs1: shapeless.Default[Person]{type Out = shapeless.::[Some[String with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("name")],String]],shapeless.::[Some[Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("age")],Int]],shapeless.HNil]]} = shapeless.Default$$anon$1@1f6a8bb8
```

P.S.

If you don't mind `Option` instead of `Some`, you can also use `AsOptions`

```
val opt = Default.AsOptions[Person]
val def3 = Default.mkDefault[Person, opt.Out](Some("aaa") :: Some(5) :: HNil)
```

Check:

```
scala> implicitly[def3.Out =:= ::[Option[String], ::[Option[Int], HNil]]]
res12: =:=[def3.Out,shapeless.::[Option[String],shapeless.::[Option[Int],shapeless.HNil]]] = <function1>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!
However in order to get the _exact_ same type, I needed to use Generic instead of LabelledGeneric. Wouldn't have found that out without your answer though, so marking as accepted :)